# Retrieving values from a Linq GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable which contains a load of dates. I wanted to group these by date and give each row a count.

I have managed to do this by dong the following:

```
 IEnumerable query = from row in stats.AsEnumerable()
                     group row by row.Field<string>("date") into grp
                     select new { Date = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count(t => t["date"] != null) };
```

(where "stats" is the datatable)

I can see from debugging that this brings back the values all grouped as I need, but now I need to loop them and get each date and count.

My problem is I don't know how to retrieve the values!

I have a foreach loop

```
foreach (var rw  in query)
{
   string date = rw.Date; // <---- this is my problem?
}
```

I don't know what type my Ienumerable is to be able to reference the values in it!

So my question is how can I retrieve each date and count for each row by doing similar to the above?

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link on my blog should help you
http://www.matlus.com/linq-group-by-finding-duplicates/

Essentially your type is an anonymous type so you can't reference it as a type but you can access the properties like you're trying to do.

I think I see your issue. If you're trying to return it from a method, you should define a type and reuturn it like shown below:

```
public IEnumerable<MyType> GetQuery()
{

  var query = from row in stats.AsEnumerable()
                    group row by row.Field<string>("date") into grp
                    select new { Date = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count(t => t["date"] != null) }; 

  foreach (var rw  in query)
  {
     yield return new MyType(rw.Date, rw.Count);
  }
}
```

declare your "query" variable using "var" as shown above.

Comment: I am returning the query from a function and I can't return it as type var. That's why I wanted a type, unless you can suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: There are other ways to do what you're trying to do (returning a linq query result) but without more details about what the calling function might possibly do with the result. I can't suggest much, except that you should probably modify the query expression to take a delegate of some sort so the calling method can pass in a delegate in order to control what the result is. does that make sense?

Comment: Shiv Kumar thanks for your reply. Sorry it doesn't make too much sense! I have decided to move your example onto my page rather than keep it in the function for the time being as that works.

Comment: In your foreach loop you could do a yield return of a specific type and your method signature will be such that it is an IEnumerable<YourType>. Then your caller can expect to get that type. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've modified my answer to show you another way in which you could achive this. Essentially if define a type that has the properties you need and then in the foreach loop, you yield rreturn an instance of that type. Your method will then be returning an IEnumerable<MyType>, where MyType is a the type you've defined.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have access to the properties of the anonymous class because you're using `IEnumerable query = ...`. Try  `var query = ...`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your comment "I am returning the query from a function", which I take to mean that you want to do the query in a method, return the data to the caller, and then iterate the data in the caller, I suggest you return a `Dictionary<DateTime, int>`, like this:

```
static Dictionary<DateTime, int> GetSummarisedData()
{
    var results = (
        from row in stats.AsEnumerable()
        group row by row.Field<string>("date") into grp
        select new { Date = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count(t => t["date"] != null) })
        .ToDictionary(val => val.Date, val => val.Count);

    return results;
}
```

then in the caller you can just

```
foreach (var kvp in GetSummarisedData())
{
    // Now kvp.Key is the date
    // and kvp.Value is the count
}
```